# How can I set up two virtual Ubuntu Web Servers and split web traffic between them based on incoming domain?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, port-forwarding, domain-name

I have a rack mount server here (HOSTA, running ubuntu 12.04), that has two virtualized installations of ubuntu (VIRTA & VIRTB, via vboxheadless, one is 12.04 and the other is 14.04). One has the newest versions of apache/mysql/php and one has older versions for some legacy web applications. All three installations of ubuntu have their own local IP addresses. I have a single external IP address that is currently mapped to example1.ddns.me (via no-ip). Currently, web traffic is then forwarded on to VIRTA via my verizon router. Now, I need to get this legacy server up and running for all of the world to see, and I am not allowed to use another port than 80, otherwise I would route port 8080 to VIRTB and be done with it.

I want all incoming web traffic to go to HOSTA and set up reverse proxying (I think?) to split example1.ddns.me on to VIRTA and example2.ddns.me on to VIRTB. Is this how reverse proxying works? Can anyone offer a walkthrough?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but load balancers such as HAproxy can do this quite trivially.  It's one more piece of the stack to manage, but worth it for the flexibility it offers, IMO.

Comment: @JimG. - Can you expand a little bit, or point me to the chapter explaining what I want to do in the reference guide? I have taken a pretty good scroll through and am not finding what I think I should be looking for.

Comment: You can use ACLs to send requests for different hostnames to different backend servers.  I'll post an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so here's the solution I ended up going with, which works nicely. For the sake of a thorough answer, I will recap some quick details.

Servers:

ServerA - ubuntu 12.04 - internal static ip of 192.168.1.230

ServerB - ubuntu 14.04 - internal static ip of 192.168.1.235

I have a website on each server, one on 12.04 (with an older php install) that i want exampleA.com to point to, and my new website on the 14.04 with new php with exampleB.com. Both Servers are running Apache2.

I have one external IP address that both domains and all subdomains are pointed to. My port forwarding on my router passes all incoming traffic on port 80 to ServerA.

Normally, all of your web files will be in /var/www/ which is set by your apache2 configuration log in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default (on ubuntu14.04 this file is /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default).

I left the default VirtualHost block to allow the original site to remain functional without changes as so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www

</VirtualHost>
```

That block may have additional configurations in it, such as a webmaster email and per-directory configurations for .htaccess and such, but the basics are that anything coming in from port 80 gets pointed to your /var/www folder and is served from there.

Below that VirtualHost block, I added a new VirtualHost block as below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName exampleb.com

  ProxyPreserveHost on
  ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.235
  ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.235
</VirtualHost>
```

This allows any traffic that comes in on port 80 (to the 192.168.1.230 address) **from exampleb.com** to then be forwarded on to 192.168.1.235 and be served from apache on that machine, due to the proxy portion. What happens there is based on that machine's apache configuration.

This setup will require the enabling of proxy in apache2, which can be done by this command in ubuntu:

```
a2enmod proxy
```

It turned out to be a very simple arrangement works perfectly for what I intended. I am sorry if this explanation isn't quite clear, feedback is welcome to improve or clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HAproxy to send requests to different backends based on the hostname using ACLs:

https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#acl

Example:

```
acl is_host1 hdr(host) -i host1.example.com
acl is_host2 hdr(host) -i host2.example.com

use backend host1_backend if is_host1
use backend host2_backend if is_host2
```

That's just a snippet, not a full working configuration, but it should get you on the right track.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look on this apache documentation:
[mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html)

You may found useful the first topic "Forward Proxies and Reverse Proxies/Gateways" and it's examples (maybe you'll need to dig a little bit more in examples in order to get it working)

Some times you will have to add some rewrite rules for urls, but will do the trick

Anyway, I will follow the recommendation made by Jim G. in the comment.

Comment: Documentation changes and links go dead. Please provide a more specific answer.

Comment: I think this is OK for this answer. The link might go dead in the future, but the function name is documented, as is the section of the document that's worth referencing. It's not one of the normal link-and-run answers we get.

Comment: if this link goes dead, is because apache 2.2 would have drop the documentation on it's version.
I won't translate it as it may been fixed most probable than removed.

The question was general enough to cover the "how do I do reverse proxy in general" and I provided a where to start reading about. You can master on the topic and answer all possible solutions for our amusement if you want to